# No 'add certificate' button in apple iOS provisioning portal

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution, digital-certificate

I am trying to follow the steps to create a "Distribution provisioning profile".  I get [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action) and the instructions tell me to "click the ‘Add Certificate’ button", but there is no button :-(  (nice one apple) I can see from the (similar) unanswered SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938845/add-certificate-button-missing-in-iphone-programme-portal) that others have this problem.  I also recall that I have had this problem before, but I can't remember how I solved it.  I am using a mac, running safari.  How do I get a button?  Help!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer to this [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1434-how-to-prepare-an-iphone-app-for-ad-hoc-distribution/) the key information was "if you already have a certificate, this option will be unavailable as you need only one".  *Really* useful information that.

Comment: I have a certificate, but it expires today. So should I "Revoke" that certificate just so I can get the "Add certificate"  button to appear?

Comment: Okay - it worked, just revoke your certificate and request a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Only Team Agents can add a Distribution profile, verify you are the Team Agent, if you are, I would suggest contacting Apple.

Comment: Yes, I am a "team agent".  I have left a comment on the forums, and lodged a bug with apple about this, and the deplorable state of the whole "provisioning" documentation generally.  All of this appears to be an old problem, and it doesn't look like Apple intends to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

BEWARE, that after you go to iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Development tab > "How to create a dev cert..." the "Choose File" command button is at the  B O T T O M   of the screen, and on a MacBook.... YOU CAN'T SEE IT unless you scroll down.